# help with continuous and differentiable theorems

Tags: functions, continuity

consider $b>a>0$ and $f:\left[a,b\right]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  $f$ is continuous at $\left[a,b\right]$ and differentiable at $\left(a,b\right)$.

also, $\frac{f\left(a\right)}{f\left(b\right)}=\:\frac{b^2}{a^2}$.
prove that exist $c$ such that $f'\left(c\right)=-\frac{2f\left(c\right)}{c}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $g(x)=x^2f(x)$ and then apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: brilliant, tnx!